# Pyinstaller with ubuntu raring errors

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have upgraded my ubuntu distribution and have since regretted it. I have been trying to get pyinstaller to package one of my applications but nothing seems to be working. I always get this traceback and I can't figure out what is actually happening to cause this. If anyone has had this issue or knows of a solution please feel free to respond!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./pyinstaller.py", line 18, in <module>
run()
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/main.py", line 88, in run
run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/main.py", line 46, in run_build
PyInstaller.build.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1732, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1681, in build
execfile(spec)
File "main.spec", line 16, in <module>
'termios',])
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/build.py", line 403, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/build.py", line 305, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/build.py", line 634, in assemble
self._check_python_library(binaries)
File "/home/servvs/Python/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/build.py", line 684, in  _check_python_library
raise IOError("Python library not found!")
IOError: Python library not found!
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libpython2.7 libpython3.3`?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-dev?